# nodejs use net module send socket

Tags: node.js, sockets

I use nodejs net module send socket like this

```
var client = new net.Socket();
client.connect('8888','127.0.0.1',function(){
    for(var i=0; i < 3; i++){
       var postData = {};
       postData.index = 0;
       client.write(JSON.stringify(postData));
    }
})
```

if I wait 200ms after send every packet , then server will recv 3 packet , and parse json normal , like this

```
 {"index":0}
 {"index":0}
 {"index":0}
```

but if I send this data in for loop block , then server just recv 1 packet , seem like these:

`{"index":0} {"index":0} {"index":0}`

any solutions ? Thanks!